# how to dynamically change indentation in a multiline string?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm using docstrings to document my code with Sphinx. I recently started to use [ruff](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/) to lint my code and It is by default applying D212 instead of D213. The only difference being that the first line of the docstring (short description) must start on the first line.

It breaks one of the decorator that I'm using ([deprecated](https://deprecated.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) as it cannot handle both types. The decorator handles docstring as followed:

```py
docstring = textwrap.dedent(wrapped.__doc__ or "")
# do stuff with docstring
```

How can I update the docstring parsing to handle docstring starting on a newline (D213) and starting on the first line (D212) the same way ?

```py
# respecting D213
def func_a():
    """
    one liner
    
    Args: 
        toto
    """

# respecting D212
def func_a():
    """one liner 
    
    Args: 
        toto
    """
```

I tried to manipulate `func_b.__doc__` in combination with `dedent` with no success.

Comment: Can't you just configure ruff to use D213 instead of D212?

Comment: My final goal is to propose a PR in deprecated libs to support both. As it's the default in ruff it will be a problem for many more people and that's not easy to diagnose

Comment: Okay, but if your goal is to submit a PR to `deprecated`, you shouldn't be messing with this in the first place. Let people have their docstring styles. *Support* both styles. Don't auto-convert one style to the other.

Comment: People do as they which, it's then parsed first by `deprecated` that add the admonition at the end and then parsed again by `napoleon`, `numpydoc` or directly as rst by `sphinx`. for user it's transparent, I'm only dealing with internal processes to avoid indentation bugs (current behavior if you use D212)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I came up with the following code:

```py
docstring = func_b.__doc__ or ""
lines = docstring.splitlines(keepends=True) or [""]
docstring = textwrap.dedent("".join(lines[1:])) if len(lines) > 1 else ""
docstring = lines[0] + docstring
```

If I feed this with `func_a` it remains unchanged and with `func_b` the indentation is set back at the start. bonus: it works as well with 1-liner docstrings.

Comment: This is doing something very different from what you asked for in the question - it's dedenting the docstrings, not converting `func_b`'s docstring to `func_a`'s format. Also, it attempts to handle empty or not-present docstrings, but `lines[0]` breaks in that case.

Comment: then let me update the question and apologies if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score -4):

```
# respecting D212
def func_b():
    """
    one liner 

    Args: 
        toto
    """
```

Comment: Hi Aditya and welcome on SO. I obviously don't want to simply change the docstring (I would have not ask the question if it was the case as I managed to write `func_a`), I want to change it programatically in `func_b.__doc__`.

Comment: I don't know that bro

Comment: Then don't answer questions when you do not know the answer. The point of ANSWERs is to answer the question. When you are told: "this doesn't help at all", then please delete your input. And better: when answering, be sure you understand the problem AND the solution you are suggesting. Blindly dropping code at people is not a good idea.